# turn rows values to columns , and count repetitions for all possible values mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas

I have a table(from log file) with emails and three other columns that contains states of that user's interaction with a system, an email(user) may have 100 or 1000 entries, each entries contain those three combinations of values, that might repeat on and on for same email and others.
something look like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| email |  val1   |  val2 |  val3   |
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
|jal@h  |  cast   | core  |   cam   |
|hal@b  |little ja| qar   |  ja sa  |
|bam@t  |  cast   | core  |   cam   |
|jal@h  |little ja| qar   |  jaja   | 
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

and so, the emails repeat, all values repeat, and there are 40+ possible values for each columns, all strings. so i want to sort distinct email email and then put all possible value as column name, and under it a count for how many this value repeated for a particular email, like so:

```
+-------+--------+--------+------+----------+-----+--------+-------+
| email | cast   |   core |  cam | little ja| qar |  ja sa | blabla |
+-------+--------+--------+------+----------+-----+--------+--------|
|jal@h  |  55    |   2    | 44   |   244    | 1   | 200    | 12     |
|hal@b  |  900   |  513   | 101  |   146    |  2  |  733   | 833    |
|bam@t  |  1231  |   33   | 433  |   411    | 933 | 833    | 53     |
+-------+--------+--------+------+----------+-----+--------+---------
```

I have tried mysql but i managed to count a certain value total occurances for each email, but not counting all possible values in each columns:

```
SELECT 
  distinct email,

  count(val1) as "cast"
FROM table1
where val1 = 'cast'
group by email
```

This query clearly doesn't do it, as it output only on value 'cast' from the first column 'val1', What i'm looking for is all distinct values in first, second, and third columns be turned to columns heads and the values in rows will be the total for that value, for a certain email 'user'.
there is a pivote table thing but i couldn't get it to work.
I'm dealing with this data as a table in mysql, but it is available in csv file, so if it isn't possible with a query, python would be a possible solution, and prefered after sql.

**update**
in python, is it possible to output the data as:

```
+-------+--------+---------+------+----------+-----+--------+-------+
|       |     val1         |      val2       |     val3              |
+-------+--------+---------+------+----------+-----+--------+-------+
| email | cast   |little ja|core  | qar      |cam  | ja sa  | jaja   |
+-------+--------+---------+------+----------+-----+--------+--------|
|jal@h  |  55    |   2     | 44   |   244    | 1   | 200    | 12     |
|hal@b  |  900   |  513    | 101  |   146    |  2  |  733   | 833    |
|bam@t  |  1231  |   33    | 433  |   411    | 933 | 833    | 53     |
+-------+--------+--------+------+----------+-----+--------+---------
```

I'm not very familiar with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use pandas, you can do a `value_counts` after grouping your data frame by email and then `unstack/pivot` it to wide format:

```
(df.set_index("email").stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
   .unstack(level=1).reset_index().fillna(0))
```

[image]

---

To get the updated result, you can group by both the email and val* columns after the `stack`:

```
(df.set_index("email").stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]).value_counts()
   .unstack(level=[1, 2]).fillna(0).sort_index(axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: it worked like a charm!!!! and the variation of values in every columns were a big number, but it was clean, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd reconstruct dataframe, then groupby and unstack with `pd.value_counts`

```
v = df.values
s = pd.Series(v[:, 1:].ravel(), v[:, 0].repeat(3))

s.groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

       cam  cast  core  ja sa  jaja  little ja  qar
bam@t    1     1     1      0     0          0    0
hal@b    0     0     0      1     0          1    1
jal@h    1     1     1      0     1          1    1
```

Comment: Thanks it went through the file smoothly, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you know the list you can calculate it using `group by`:

```
SELECT email,
       sum(val1 = 'cast') as `cast`,
       sum(val1 = 'core') as `core`,
       sum(val1 = 'cam') as `cam`,
       . . .
FROM table1
GROUP BY email;
```

The `. . .` is for you to fill in the remaining values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query to generate a PREPARED Statement dynamic from your Values val1-val3 in your table:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( "SELECT email,\n",
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT ("  SUM(IF('",val1,"' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS '",val1,"'")
        SEPARATOR ',\n'),
        "\nFROM table1\nGROUP BY EMAIL\nORDER BY email") INTO @myquery
FROM (
    SELECT val1 FROM table1
    UNION SELECT val2 FROM table1
    UNION SELECT val3 FROM table1
) AS vals
ORDER BY val1;

-- ONLY TO VERIFY QUERY
SELECT @myquery;

PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**sample table**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+-----------+------+-------+
| id | email | val1      | val2 | val3  |
+----+-------+-----------+------+-------+
|  1 | jal@h | cast      | core | cam   |
|  2 | hal@b | little ja | qar  | ja sa |
|  3 | bam@t | cast      | core | cam   |
|  4 | jal@h | little ja | qar  | cast  |
+----+-------+-----------+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**generate query**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT( "SELECT email,\n",
    ->         GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->             CONCAT ("  SUM(IF('",val1,"' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS '",val1,"'")
    ->         SEPARATOR ',\n'),
    ->         "\nFROM table1\nGROUP BY EMAIL\nORDER BY email") INTO @myquery
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT val1 FROM table1
    ->     UNION SELECT val2 FROM table1
    ->     UNION SELECT val3 FROM table1
    -> ) AS vals
    -> ORDER BY val1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
```

**verify query**

```
mysql> -- ONLY TO VERIFY QUERY
mysql> SELECT @myquery;

SELECT email,
  SUM(IF('cast' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'cast',
  SUM(IF('little ja' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'little ja',
  SUM(IF('core' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'core',
  SUM(IF('qar' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'qar',
  SUM(IF('cam' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'cam',
  SUM(IF('ja sa' IN(val1,val2,val3),1,0)) AS 'ja sa'
FROM table1
GROUP BY EMAIL
ORDER BY email

1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

**execute query**

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+-------+------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
| email | cast | little ja | core | qar  | cam  | ja sa |
+-------+------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
| bam@t |    1 |         0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |     0 |
| hal@b |    0 |         1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |     1 |
| jal@h |    2 |         1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |     0 |
+-------+------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```